# How to test controller methods that use HEAD in Phoenix

Tags: testing, phoenix-framework, plug

Currently the documentation is clear and vibrant with the common `HTTP` verbs, but we started implementing some `HEAD` routes today and it is not tested the same way as the others.

To test say a `GET` method:

`conn = get conn, controller_path(conn, :controller_method, params)`

So I would assume you would just change `get` to `head`, but this is not the case.

Here is my route:

`template_journeys_count_path  HEAD    /v1/templates/:template_id/journeys        GondorWeb.V1.JourneyController :count`

and my controller method:

`def count(conn, %{"template_id" => template_id}) do
    count = Templates.get_journey_count(template_id)
    conn
    |> put_resp_header("x-total-count", count)
    |> send_resp(204, "")
 end`

and my test:

`conn = head conn, template_journeys_count_path(conn, :count, template.id)
assert response(conn, 204)`

But I am getting an error saying no response received and the `resp_header` that I added what not in `conn.resp_headers`

Am I missing something? I also tried to set up a connection build using `Plug.ConnTest`'s method `build_conn` passing the `HEAD` method into it but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

OK after more reading and testing using postman. Phoenix will automatically change `HEAD` requests into `GET` requests, there for when phoenix was looking for my route in the router, it was hitting the `get` route that matched the path with was my `:index` method.

For `HEAD` routes:

- the verb in the router must be a `get`, ex: `get '/items', :index`
- if you want to share a path, just add the `put_resp_header` on your returned connection in the controller method, only the header will be sent in the response
- It is ok that the response code is not a 204, as per the [w3c doc's](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) `HEAD` requests can have a 200 response
- testing a `HEAD` request, you can just change a the `get` to a `head` and test the response_headers and that no body was sent.

To show my changes... here is my router:

`get "/journeys", JourneyController, :index`

my controller method:

```
def index(conn, %{"template_id" => template_id}) do
    journeys = Templates.list_journeys(template_id)
    conn
    |> put_resp_header("x-total-count", "#{Enum.count(journeys)}")
    |> render("index.json", journeys: journeys)
end
```

and my test:

```
test "gets count", %{conn: conn, template: template} do
  conn = head conn, template_journey_path(conn, :index, template.id)
  assert conn.resp_body == ""
  assert Enum.at(get_resp_header(conn, "x-total-count"), 0) == "1"
end
```